# Dictionary of class subclasses

Tags: python, oop

Whether there is a way to make the dictionary of all class inheritances ?

Something like

```
 class MagikClass :

       pass

 class A(MagikClass) :

       __name__ = "A"

 print magik_dict # -> { "A": A }
```

Comment: What's wrong with grep?  `grep 'class.*MagikClass' *.py` seems like it would work perfectly.

Comment: @S.Lott It won't work for the obvious extension to the problem: `class B(A):`. Furthermore, if other parts of the python program are to work with this information, you'll have to use subprocess and parsing to aquire the information, which is not nearly as elegant as the solutions below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution that adds an attribute `_derived` to each class, containing the derived classes of that class:

```
class Meta(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, dict_):
        new_class = type.__new__(cls, name, bases, dict_)
        new_class._derived = {}
        if isinstance(bases[0], Meta):
            bases[0]._derived[name] = new_class
        return new_class

class Magic(object):
    __metaclass__ = Meta

class A(Magic):
    pass

class B(Magic):
    pass

print Magic._derived
```

prints

```
{'A': <class '__main__.A'>, 'B': <class '__main__.B'>}
```